# How to get data from ejabberd packet object?

Tags: xml, xmpp, ejabberd, erl, ejabberd-module

I have a print log with packet data and I extract subelement using `Packet#message.sub_els` and it gives me array like :

```
[
    {xmlel,<<"delay">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"urn:xmpp:delay">>},{<<"stamp">>,<<"2019-10-24T08:08:15.126+00:00">>}],[]},
    {xmlel,<<"type">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"urn:xmpp:media">>}],[{xmlcdata,<<"1">>}]},
    {xmlel,<<"media">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"urn:xmpp:data">>}],[{xmlcdata,<<"null">>}]},
    {xmlel,<<"extra">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"urn:xmpp:extra">>}],[{xmlcdata,<<"{\"type\":\"chat\",\"id\":\"5d666434ae920b04875c0a57\",\"name\":\"X003\",\"username\":\"x003\",\"status\":\"\",\"profile_picture\":\"\"}">>}]},
    {xmlel,<<"request">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"urn:xmpp:receipts">>}],[]},
    {xmlel,<<"request">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"urn:xmpp:read">>}],[]}
],
```

I want to extra type, media, extra. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Got some methods, using that I have extracted necessary data and attribute value.

```
AllElm = Packet#message.sub_els,
    ?INFO_MSG("BinaryData ~p",[fxml:element_to_binary(AllElm)]),
    ?INFO_MSG("PacketsData ~p",[AllElm]),
    %Test = fxml:get_path_s(Packet, [{elem, <<"type">>}]),
Delay = fxml:get_path_s(xmpp:encode(Packet), [{elem,list_to_binary("delay")}, {attr, list_to_binary("stamp")}]),
    ?INFO_MSG("PacketsDataDelay ~p",[Delay]),
Type = fxml:get_path_s(xmpp:encode(Packet), [{elem,list_to_binary("type")}, cdata]),
    ?INFO_MSG("PacketsDataType ~p",[Type]),
Media = fxml:get_path_s(xmpp:encode(Packet), [{elem,list_to_binary("media")}, cdata]),
    ?INFO_MSG("PacketsDataMedia ~p",[Media]),
Extra = fxml:get_path_s(xmpp:encode(Packet), [{elem,list_to_binary("extra")}, cdata]),
    ?INFO_MSG("PacketsDataExtra ~p",[Extra]),
```